# Copy a cell and paste into first blank row in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a cell from one worksheet and paste the value into the first blank cell in a range of cells on another worksheet.

I found some code that almost works but it pastes the formatting and formula.

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("GHIN").Range("D151")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Monthly").Range("I56").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

This works except I want it to paste special values only.

Comment: change `r1.Copy r2` to `r2 = r1`

Comment: Thank You!  This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("Monthly").Range("I56").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheets("GHIN").Range("D151").Value`

Comment: add context. (From Review).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code bellow.

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("GHIN").Range("D151")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Monthly").Range("I56").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    '//Copy r1 (cell format, value...)
    r1.Copy

    '//Paste special in the desired cell. You can add/change parameters if you want
    r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```